# Laravel routes the right or better way

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I am new with Laravel and I was wondering is there a big difference in using routes basically and with my way:

Instead of using:

```
Route::get('/','PagesController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about')->name('about');
Route::get('/contact','PagesController@contact')->name('contact');

And methods just return views...
```

I am using:

```
Route::get('/{page?}','PagesController@index')
->where(['page'=>'about|contact'])->name('page');

public function index($page = 'home') {
    return view($page);
}
```

With second example I can remove a lot of lines of code, since `resource controller` is not the best option for my needs.

So are there any bad reasons why shouldn't I use routes my way?

Thanks

Comment: [View routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#view-routes) might also be an option

Comment: @apokryfos yeah, but still I need to add for each route same thing. If I have 10 pages that just load views. Its 10 lines or in my way I just need to name file same as route and put it in where array for "page" values.

Comment: The first example you provide is the cleanest way, and you wouldn't need to use a resource controller. I'd suggest splitting your controllers up by pages too. So your about route would point to the AboutController@index

Comment: First it's more readable and make sense to use controller for each page you have.
The problem in your example is it gets complicated over time and your website grows. Like if you want to pass data to your views how would you do that in your way ?

Comment: First is the best for me, because you're more flexibel and have a quick overview without calling `php artisan route:list` via a console line tool.

Comment: 10 routes are easier to manage than a regex with 10 `|` I think

Comment: your second example makes your code more obfuscated/unmaintainable for no benefit. You don't need to have a full resource controller, but you can still have a tidy implementation.Just return the view directly from the route as mentioned by @apokryfos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it doesn't take that much time or effort, I would also suggest being explicit as this gives you much more control in the future. 
Plus with your current implementation you're going to have to add to where clause every time you want to add a new page so it wouldn't be saving you that much time anyway.

One way to simplify your routes file would be to use [view()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#view-routes) rather than `get()`:

```
Route::view('about', 'about')->name('about');
```

---

An middle of the road option would be to add your simple views to an array and have something like:

```
$basicViews = ['about', 'contact'];

foreach ($basicViews as $basicView) {
    Route::view($basicView, $basicView)->name($basicView);
}
```

I'm not saying you should go with this approach but there are benefits in comparison to using a `PageController` and a regex string:

- All of the routes involved can clearly be seen and everything is contained in your routes file.
- Routes can still be named.
- You don't have to worry as much about potentially have a very long regex string

If you need to change the uri, blade file name or route name then I would definitely suggest going be to being explicit rather than trying to overcomplicate things.

Comment: You are probably right, its funny but I hate to see 100+ files with 10 lines of code :D LIke in my way I can do everything I need but its messy and it has much less code and files. Regular option is as everyone else suggested but it bugs me to open web.php file and see 50 lines with same routes like 10 for basic pages, login post and get....
`Route::get('/{user?}/{post?}/{action?}','UsersController@index')
->where(['action'=>'edit|delete'])
->name('user');`
This is one example I use otherwise I would use 4 routes:
user, user/post, user/post/edit, user/post/delete...

Comment: @Learner I know exactly what you mean and I think most of us have been through that at one point or another but it's when making things too simple goes wrong that causes us more grief than the issue we're trying to avoid in the first place, or as pointed out in another comment, makes it harder to understand when we come back to it after x amount of time. I would genuinely suggest going with the `foreach` option over the `where` option though.

Comment: @Learner As for your `user.post.{action}` issue you can always just use `Route::resource()` inside a `Route::group` or (not in this case) but say you accepted the `$userId` as well you can use nested resources i.e. `Route::resource('user.post', 'UserPostController')`

Comment: I have problems with resource route, it works as default and if I don't need one route to be get but post I can't (don't know how to change it) and then I need to create new method and add anyway new line. And if I dont use all default methods either I need to specify which I use or which I dont... So its a pain to use resource in my most cases...

Comment: @Learner If you're having to change the route methods then resource is not for you.

Comment: Well I accepted your answer, and I will change back everything while I still can haha :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any evident security issues or logical faults to declaring routes your way.

**TL;DR**

> There are reasons Laravel does its things a certain way; following
>   standards might prove useful down the line.

On the other hand, I can some a few advantages to writing those few lines of code you are trying to avoid:

**1. Readability**

It's quite easy to see a list of available pages when they are lined up like in the first example, versus digging through the `where` call and its argument.

**2. Maintenance and upgradability**

For you, at this point in time, it seems like the easiest and fastest way to use a dynamic page caller, but for you in 2 years, or another programmer, it might make a lot more sense to have all the routes broken down into smaller pieces. What you aren't implementing yet doesn't mean it will never be. If you need to add some variables to your views later on, it will be much easier to jump into that method call and add them.

**3. Using named routes**

In an eventual case where you'd need to change some Urls, using named routes in your blade templates would save you time; a technique you can't really use with a dynamic page caller.

Comment: In my opinion which is probably wrong **1.** Readability is something with less code for me and less files.
**2.** I can call variables through that one method that controls views.
**3.** I can use route('page', ['about']) as example